# windows heat template user_data can not work

Tags: heat

I am new to CloudbaseInit. I have setup a image with CloudbaseInit,and can build the machine with new password and expand hdd size all ok (using command :nova boot). But I want to use heat stack-create with a heat template file

```
   heat_template_version: 2013-05-23

description: dtb test hottest,for test add parameters.

parameters:
  flavor:
    type: string
    label: paasflavor
    description: paasflavor  flavor to be used
    default: c1m2h90
  availability_zone:
    type: string
    description: The Availability Zone to launch the instance.
    default: nova
  name:
    type: string
    description: name of host.

resources:
  server1_port1:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:
      network_id: 70c1faf0-51f6-4cb9-b324-7bc2cc6fab5b

  server1:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      name: { get_param: name }
      image: template_win2008
      flavor: { get_param: flavor }
      availability_zone: { get_param: availability_zone }
      networks:
        - port: { get_resource: server1_port1 }
      user_data:
        echo 11 > \"c:\\yp\\333"\n,

outputs:
  server1_ip:
    description: Private IP address of server1
    value: { get_attr: [ server1, first_address ] }
```

Machine builds ok. When I login into it, and go to c:\yp, I find nothing. I think user_data is wrong, and command not work. I have tried several other ways for writing user_data part, but all failed. I never build windows machine with heat template.

Answer (score 0):

Add pipe(|) after user_data:
 user_data: |